# Tinymce web page integration has menu icon covered by blue color

Tags: icons, tinymce, hide

Just integrated the new tinymce-6 on a webpage. It works correctly but the  icons of the menu or toolbars are  hidden under a blue color??? can anyone help? regards.

in the header part of my html i have

and under the form in the body part of the web page :

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                 /*<![CDATA[*/
                  
                    tinymce.init({
                    selector: '#content',
                    menubar: 'insert',
                    plugins: 'ai tinycomments mentions anchor autolink charmap codesample emoticons image link lists media searchreplace table visualblocks wordcount checklist mediaembed casechange export formatpainter pageembed permanentpen footnotes advtemplate advtable advcode editimage tableofcontents mergetags powerpaste tinymcespellchecker autocorrect a11ychecker typography inlinecss',
                    toolbar: 'undo redo | blocks fontfamily fontsize | bold italic underline strikethrough | link image media table mergetags | align lineheight | tinycomments | checklist numlist bullist indent outdent | emoticons charmap | removeformat',
                    image_prepend_url: 'https://scibricks.com/blogs/posts/',
                    a11y_advanced_options: true,
                    ai_request: (request, respondWith) => respondWith.string(() => Promise.reject("See docs to implement AI Assistant")),
                    width: 800,
                    height: 400
                    }); 
                 /*]]>*/
                </script>
```

I'm expecting to have the menu icons displayed   and not hidden.